# Меньший приоритет для Spacer в SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Изучаю SwiftUI. Столкнулся с `Picker` внутри `Form`. Он, кажется, супер удобным, но иконка с галочкой справа не совсем нравится. Вариантов по трансформации внешнего вида не нашел и решил сделать свой. Но, столкнулся со странным поведением `Spacer()`.

Пример:
[image: Скриншот 1]
Здесь, **Picker A** - это стандартный Picker с элементарным кодом:

```
Picker("Picker A", selection: $selectedCurrency) {
    ForEach(currencies) { currency in
        Text(currency.title)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .tag(currency.id)
    }
}
.pickerStyle(DefaultPickerStyle())
```

**Picker B** - кастомный (мой):

```
NavigationLink(
    destination: CurrencyListView(currency: $currency),
    label: {
        Text("Picker B")
        Spacer()
        if currency != nil {
            Text(currency!.title)
                .lineLimit(1)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }
    }
)
```

Проблема в обрезании выбранного значения. В случае, если выбранное значение полностью помещается в ячейку (не мешая левой части), то, кажется логичным показывать его полностью (как в дефолтном Picker'е). Проблема решается с помощью `.fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)` у обоих `Text`. Но если так сделать, то в случае, если будет выбрано что-то с длинным названием, то chevron стрелка уезжает за пределы ячейки вправо. В Apple же продумали такой кейс и решили его по-своему:
[image: Скриншот 2]

Я пробовал использовать `.layoutPriority()`, но это не сработало. Пытался определить ширину правого `Text` до `Spacer`, что бы просчитать его ширину до отображения. Но толкового решения тоже не нашел. Вариант с определением кол-ва символов - костыль
Есть у кого-то идеи как можно решить такую задачку? Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте `frame`:

```swift
Text(title)
    .lineLimit(1)
    .foregroundColor(.gray)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]